# How are anchor values choosen in yolov2-tiny.cfg?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

In **yolov2-tiny.cfg**, the anchors are given as:-

`anchors =  0.57273, 0.677385, 1.87446, 2.06253, 3.33843, 5.47434, 7.88282, 3.52778, 9.77052, 9.16828`

What values are these? Is it height, width or something?
Can someone explain me this.

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers are widths and heights. If you group those numbers it will form sets of width and height, like this

```
(0.57273, 0.677385), (1.87446, 2.06253), (3.33843, 5.47434), (7.88282, 3.52778), (9.77052, 9.16828)
```

As you can see, there are 5 parenthesis which means there are **5 different anchor boxes** for each grid. For example Yolo divides the input image to 13x13 grid, so each grid will have 5 correspondents anchor boxes. Those values are just **initial values** or default values that have been set by the author, later the box **will be resized** to the closest predicted object. So the network will adjust the size of nearest anchor box to the size of predicted object.

Why 5? In case of Yolo V2 it has 5 anchor boxes, while Yolo V3 has 9 anchor boxes for higher IOU.

How to generate anchor boxes for your custom dataset? You have to use K-Means clustering to generate the anchors. For example use Alexey's repo : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/scripts/gen_anchors.py

For more detail discussion, refer to the github link : https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/568 
For more detail about Anchor box and K-Means clustering, jump to section 3 https://medium.com/@vivek.yadav/part-1-generating-anchor-boxes-for-yolo-like-network-for-vehicle-detection-using-kitti-dataset-b2fe033e5807